# malloc: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list

Tags: c++, xcode, pointers, malloc, objective-c++

I have some C++ code in my OS X project that allocates an array thusly:

```
C * p = new C[lengthHint + 2];
```

This is in a template class; `C` is `unsigned short`. `lengthHint` is 1. This is all irrelevant. The error I get at runtime is:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x60800000c4f0: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

It appears `malloc` is failing because a previous call to `free` freed something that wasn't valid. But it seems like `free` would've complained about that at the time.

Obviously there are millions of `malloc/free` and `new/delete` calls being executed and this same code is running without issues in other programs running on iOS and OS X. I'm not sure how to approach debugging this and am looking for suggestions.

Comment: @Craig: In any case, it looks like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) runs on OS X, so I'd start with that.

Comment: @Craig - `set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`  Well did you do that?  I don't use XCode, but if this is what it says to do, I think you should try and do this.  Then get a look at the call stack.

Comment: As @Mike Seymour mentions valgrind is probably your best answer to *find* this problem. However you can completely *prevent* such problems entirely by just not doing manual memory management (smart pointers and proper containers).

Comment: Paul, the error is raised in `malloc`, so breaking at `malloc_error_break` produces the same call stack as I was seeing, which is where I got the line of code reproduced in the question.

Comment: Mark, completely rewriting the program to use smart pointers is like suggesting that I fix the dome light in my car by riding a bicycle. There's nothing wrong with riding a bike, but the question was about fixing the light. The programmers who implement smart pointers are using good old-fashioned memory management under the hood, so bugs aren't avoided, they just move. This code has been around for 16 years and runs on a half-dozen platforms. Coincidentally it's in our implementation of smart pointers, allowing users of this particular class not to worry about memory management. (more...)

Comment: ... The question was about how to approach debugging of this particular problem, since by the time I'm told about it, the free list is already corrupted. I was hoping to find someone with more experience with this kind of thing, since I've been doing C/C++ memory management for 30 years now and just don't run into problems like this. valgrind is a good suggestion though it apparently doesn't run on the later versions of OS X.

Comment: @Craig Presumably the bug is in allocation code NOT managed by the internal smart pointer, not in the smart pointer code itself. This is further concurred by the fact that other apps function correctly. Is there any chance to compile the problematic app on Linux and run valgrind there? Even if you don't see the problem symptoms, it can still help find the root problem if the error can be detected.

Comment: My point was that smart pointers are implemented under the hood using standard allocation and release and are thus subject to the same potential issues as using that technology directly. They do, however, help prevent junior programmers from making mistakes that they would be likely to make when handed power tools like `malloc` and `free`. My problem turned out not to be as hard to find as I originally thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I suspected, the problem didn't had anything to do with the `malloc` call. I had decided to ignore the problem while I worked on another issue. The project was one where I was moving some code previously written in C++ for Windows over to Mac. While changing some type names I inadvertently changed this:

```
TCHAR * p = new TCHAR[(length + 1)];
```

to this:

```
char * p = new char(length + 1);
```

So just a typo, but one with pretty significant implications.

I discovered this while reviewing recent changes to a file that had some other odd behavior. So the answer to my original question was pretty simple and applies in a lot of other situations: "What have you changed lately?" :-)

Comment: "What have you changed lately?" :)

Comment: @Aaron I also did the same thing, but what's the issue with writing this ? Isn't TCHAR a char ? noob question may be but i am new with C++ and also facing the same issue.

Comment: @AmitHooda it depends on what you're asking about. In my old code that I was porting, char is 8-bit and TCHAR is either 8 or 16 bits, depending on whether or not UNICODE is turned on. So they were potentially different. Second, my real problem was leaving out the square brackets when converting  to char *. That is what I am pointing out in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it does not relate to your case, but wanted to share some tricky bug I've got to with "malloc: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list" error.
For me it was error in the following code:
       `int *array = malloc(len+1 * sizeof(int));`
Since I'm newbie in C, I've missed here that `malloc(len+1 * sizeof(int))` incorrectly assumes C Operator Precedence.
Obviously it must be:
      `malloc((len+1) * sizeof(int))`

Comment: I'll just leave this question here and it can serve as a confessional for C/C++ typos. :-)